# Oversize JPanel in WindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, gridbaglayout, windowbuilder

I am designing a large form with the [Eclipse WindowBuilder plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). The class extends `JPanel` and uses `GridBagLayout` as its `LayoutManager`.

Now my panel has become vertically larger than my screen size and I cannot make the `JPanel` any larger by dragging its borders.

How can I vertically extend the `JPanel` so it's still usabe with WindowBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

> Now my panel has become vertically larger than my screen size and I
>   cannot make the JPanel any larger by dragging its borders.
>
> How can I vertically extend the JPanel so it's still usabe with
>   WindowBuilder?

- put [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) to the [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: I already tried that, but it's not usable either. When I want to add more lines to the GridBagLayout, it always resizes to the screen height.

Comment: *"I already tried that"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Usually I'd do that, but this is _not_ a SSCCE question.